# Firebase cloud messaging for iOS: don't receive notifications from POST request (only from composer tool)

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I setup Firebase cloud messaging for iOS using their quick start tutorial and API docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message
I sent message to my iPhone from Firebase composer tool and it was successful. But the next step I need is to receive a notification sent with regular POST request. I found that it's possible to do with legacy protocols: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_legacy_protocol_send_requests
I tried to send the following:

```
{ "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!"
  },
  "to" : "myIphoneTokenHere"
}
```

via postman with authorization key for my Firebase project and received success in response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 5644065455367933439,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1513338642327024%5529b926f9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I there was no notification on my iPhone unlike with the composer tool.
Wondering what can I try to solve this problem, how can I debug what goes wrong?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to handle the incoming messages. That code should be in your `AppDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by changing request body to:

```
{
"content_available": true,
"notification" : {
"body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
"title" : "FCM Message"}, "to" : "myIphoneTokenHere" }
```